# Pattern matching to match longest substring

Tags: java, regex

I have this regex `D+U`.

It should match once for the following String `UDDDUDUU`  but with Java it matches three times. It matches `DDDU` `DU`. I am using https://regex101.com/ to check my regex, and it should only match once, the `DDDU`.

I am trying to solve this [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/counting-valleys/submissions/code/84730702) challenge. I am also trying to use Pattern's because I want to practice using those classes.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
static int match(int n, String s) {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("D+U").matcher(s);
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (matcher.find(i)) {
        count++;
        i = matcher.end() + 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: If you're simply looking for the longest match, you'll need to iterate over all matches and pick the longest one yourself.

Comment: I added more context @NPE

Comment: Link can't be only resource about problem you are trying to solve. If link breaks (which happens quite often) question will be unclear. Describe what your code is supposed to do within question in a way which wouldn't *require* others to visit link.

Comment: You seem to want a mere `[UD]+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex `+` match one or more of the preceding character/regular expression. So this will match any sequence of `D` and the `U`.

If you want to return the longest match you could do:

```
static String match(String s) {
    ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("D+U").matcher(s);
    int i = 0;
    while (matcher.find(i)) {
       matches.add(matcher.group());
       i = matcher.end();
    }   
    return Collections.max(matches, Comparator.comparing(c -> c.length()));
}
```

Which (with the test case of `UDDDUDUU`) returns `DDDU`. Also note that I removed the parameter of `n` as you never used it

Comment: I added more context. This does not solve the problem, thanks.

Comment: @Pants I cannot access the link. What is this method supposed to do?